# Special characters are being displayed in webpage

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a webpage with a `News` section, I'm getting those news from a blog and sending them to my database, then, I'm getting them from my database and displaying it in my webpage, firstly I'm just displaying the title and some text, and once the text or the title is clicked then it will send you to the blog and you can read the complete new. The only thing is that when I'm displaying partially the text firstly I'm displaying too the `reserved characters`. For example the partial news are being displayed firstly like this:

```
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.&nbsp; &nbsp;Lorem Ipsum 
has been the industry's standard dummy ...<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~f/feedburner/eqsfD/~4/Dsdfg_fPs" height="1" width="1" alt=""/
```

This is my code:

```
@foreach (var itemBlogList in Model.BlogList)
{
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a href="@itemBlogList.Link">  <h3 class="panel-title">@itemBlogList.Title</h3> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

                @Html.DisplayFor( i => itemBlogList.Text)          
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What can I do so those special characters are not displayed too?

Comment: Sounds like you are storing / retrieving the text as a string rather than HTML.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is there any way that I can get that text from the database and show it as html?

Comment: That's beyond me unfortunately. I just recognise the symptoms. I don't know the cure.

Comment: Use `Html.Raw()`. Read remarks here for full explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896.aspx

Comment: @LeandroTaset you're right. Now it works :) You should put it as an answer so it can be helpful for other readers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `@Html.DisplayFor` helper. Try `@Html.Raw` instead.

```
@foreach (var itemBlogList in Model.BlogList)
{
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a href="@itemBlogList.Link">  <h3 class="panel-title">@itemBlogList.Title</h3> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

                @Html.Raw( i => itemBlogList.Text)          
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

More info [**HtmlHelper.Raw Method (String)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896.aspx)